# Left DRL not working - High Beam Is (Honda Integra Type-S)

Tags: honda, headlight, integra

I have a 2005 Type-S and can't get the left DRL to work.
I'm pretty sure these share the same bulb with the high-beam so it's strange that the high-beam works but the DRL doesn't.
I replaced the bulb and checked the fuses but they seem ok (unless DRL has it's own fuse)...
The fuse I checked was under the bonnet no.15

Any ideas what else it could be?

[1. Under Bonnet Fuse Box](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-YyGfqZaHLC6bbMiMwBug41gpxBfv2iw/view)

[2. Interior Fuse Box](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NlNv7o43ozdkKT4UBamZKt2xq-txXS-f/view)

Comment: there are 2 headlamp fuses, 15 and 17. DRL should be low beams by default.

Comment: looks like you have a bad bulb on the left side.

Comment: The fuse would take out both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my old Civic that the contacts on light bulb socket where corroded, especially on the left side. Check this and clean/replace if necessary.